# Image not rendered in pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am sending a pdf binary string from the backend to the fronted. While the pdf renders successfully, it does not render the images. Assuming that the conversion to binary was the issue in backend, I compiled the binary and the generated pdf rendered images.

So the problem is in the frontend.

```
const binaryString = "%PDF-1.3\n%\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\n1 0 obj\n<< /Creator <feff0050007200610077006e>\n/Producer <feff0050007200610077006e>\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<< /Type /Catalog\n/Pages 3 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<< /Type /Pages\n/Count 1\n/Kids [5 0 R]\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<< /Length 129\n>>\nstream\nq\n\nBT\n36.0 747.384 Td\n/F1.0 12 Tf\n[<48656c6c6f2057> 30 <6f72> -15 <6c64>] TJ\nET\n\n\nq\n32.0 0.0 0.0 32.0 36.0 710.128 cm\n/I1 Do\nQ\nQ\n\nendstream\nendobj\n5 0 obj\n<< /Type /Page\n/Parent 3 0 R\n/MediaBox [0 0 612.0 792.0]\n/CropBox [0 0 612.0 792.0]\n/BleedBox [0 0 612.0 792.0]\n/TrimBox [0 0 612.0 792.0]\n/ArtBox [0 0 612.0 792.0]\n/Contents 4 0 R\n/Resources << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]\n/Font << /F1.0 6 0 R\n>>\n/XObject << /I1 7 0 R\n>>\n>>\n>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<< /Type /Font\n/Subtype /Type1\n/BaseFont /Helvetica\n/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding\n>>\nendobj\n7 0 obj\n<< /Type /XObject\n/Subtype /Image\n/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/BitsPerComponent 8\n/Width 32\n/Height 32\n/Length 653\n/Filter [/DCTDecode]\n>>\nstream\n\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xFF\xDB\x00C\x00\t\x06\a\b\a\x06\t\b\a\b\n\n\t\v\r\x16\x0F\r\f\f\r\e\x14\x15\x10\x16 \x1D\"\" \x1D\x1F\x1F$(4,$&1'\x1F\x1F-=-157:::#+?D?8C49:7\xFF\xDB\x00C\x01\n\n\n\r\f\r\x1A\x0F\x0F\x1A7%\x1F%77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777\xFF\xC0\x00\x11\b\x00 \x00 \x03\x01\"\x00\x02\x11\x01\x03\x11\x01\xFF\xC4\x00\x18\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x05\a\x03\x04\xFF\xC4\x00-\x10\x00\x02\x01\x04\x00\x04\x04\x04\a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x00\x04\x05\x11\x06\x12AQ\x13\x142\x81\x15!1\xB1Raqr\x91\xC1\xF0\xFF\xC4\x00\x1A\x01\x00\x01\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x01\x02\x03\x05\x06\xFF\xC4\x00#\x11\x00\x01\x03\x03\x03\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x03\x11\x00\x041\x05!A\x12\x13\"$Qq\xFF\xDA\x00\f\x03\x01\x00\x02\x11\x03\x11\x00?\x00\xD92\xF7\xDF\x0E\xB1i\x82\xF3\xC8HH\xD3\xF11\xFA\x0F\xF7j\x88\xD8\xF4\xB8\"|\xBC\xAFq1\x1F1\xBD*~@\n\xA1\xC5\n\xDEF\t\xC0\xDA\xDB\xDC$\xAF\xFBF\xC7\xF7R2\x19\x84\xB0\x8C\xCA\xCB\x13\xF3\x10\x13\xC4$\x02}\x81\xFBW5\xAB?\xEC\x06\x9C>1\xB6`\x9F\xBBf\x8D\xB7D\xA6Fk\x912c$3b\x1D\x95G\xAE\x16<\xCA\xE3\xDF\xE8im\x85\xD2^\xD9\xC5s\x17\xA6E\xDE\xBB\x1E\xA3\xD8\xD1ho\xA2\x9B\x1C\xB9\x19#H\x83.\xCA\x03\xD7\xB7\xF3Wxn\a\xB7\xC2ZG(\xD3r\x96\xD7\xEAI\x1Fz\xAF@\xB8uO8\xD4\xCA\x06?f\x9E\xE8'\xA4\x1Ej\x93(e*\xC0\x10F\x88=h\x06i\xF1\xF6\xE9\x94\xC5\xDCO\nI\n\xB1\x81\x1D\xB5\xAD\xAF2\x81\xBE\xA3u\xA0P\x1E.\xC0\xE4\x17-w\x95\xB6\xB4\xF3\xB6\xF3\xAAsE\x18V\x91J\x80\xBE\x96F\xDF\xB5m_\xE9\xED\xDE\xA1)Q\x82\f\x82(V\xDD-\x9D\xAB\xD5\x878\xEB\xFC\xB5\xA5\x8D\x9C\x91Iki\x01\x98\xC6\xAD\xCC7\xB0\x06\xFB\x90H4\xD2\x85\xF0.\x0E\xEE\xDA\xEEl\xAD\xE4\x1ETI\x0F\x85\x15\xB9\x000\e\x04\x96\x00\x00>`t\xEFM*V\x16(\xB2k\xB6\x83<\xC9\xCD'\x1C+2k\xFF\xD9\nendstream\nendobj\nxref\n0 8\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000015 00000 n \n0000000109 00000 n \n0000000158 00000 n \n0000000215 00000 n \n0000000395 00000 n \n0000000706 00000 n \n0000000803 00000 n \ntrailer\n<< /Size 8\n/Root 2 0 R\n/Info 1 0 R\n>>\nstartxref\n1623\n%%EOF\n"

const blob = new Blob([binaryString], {type: 'application/pdf'});
window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

This is how i am converting the binary string to pdf in frontend. the text renders perfectly but the image fails to render.

PS: I have attached a working pdf binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the backed, convert the binary string to base64 `Base64.encode64(pdf.render)`

then in the frontend conver the base64 back to binary, where `data` is the converted base64 coming form the server

```
const binaryString = atob(data);
 const len = binaryString.length;
        const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
        const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
          view[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const blob = new Blob([view], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```